# How can I describe the tenths digit with an even number?

Tags: terminology

How can I describe the following numbers?

```
0.2
0.4
0.6
0.8
```

Can I call them "even tenths"?

For example:

"If the maximum value in the data set is 1, then the values displayed in the bar graph are the **______**." I am pertaining to the numbers above.

Comment: Cross-posted from http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171348/how-do-i-describe-even-values-of-the-tenths-digit-of-a-number

Answer (score 4):

They can be called "fifths" as $\frac 15 = 0.2$

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a good way to say this (at least not in English). If you are trying to be precise and are willing to be wordy, you could say "$x$ such that $10x$ is an even integer."